# Laravel 5: Store artisan console table output in a variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

In Laravel 5 console commands, you can output a table like so:

```
$this->table($headers, $tableData);
```

This is described here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#writing-output

However this outputs it straight to the console.

How can I store it in a variable without sending the data to the console.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to catch the output.

```
ob_start();
$this->table($headers, $tableData);
$table = ob_get_flush();
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a more "proper" way. But will test it out.

Comment: Laravel uses the [Symfony Table class](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/master/Helper/Table.php) for this and this class requires you to provide an [`OutputInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/master/Output/OutputInterface.php), so I think output buffering would be the easiest solution.